# delete records in foxpro 2.x using oledb connection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, oledb, foxpro

hi there 
first of all im completed excited to use for first time this incredible forum

my question is, if somebody knows how to physically delete a Fox pro 2.x record from C#.net using an OleDb connection, because i used a simple and standard delete sql statement like 'delete from table where condition' and the compiler throws me an exception that i have a sintax error.

p.s. im mexican so please be considered about my english, im not pretty good at all.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum.  Welcome to our programming Q&A!

Comment: I'm looking at historic, unanswered questions... Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the code you used? As the simple delete from table where condition should indeed work just fine.

Did you use a DBCommand with .ExecuteNonQuery() ?

In general the pattern is basically this...

```
    IDbConnection c = GetYourConnectionOrNewOneUp();
    using (IDbCommand cmd = c.CreateCommand())
    {
      cmd.CommandText = "delete from yourtable where yourfield = 'value'";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
                        conecction.ConnectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;" + "Data Source={0}", myDataSource);

                        conecction.Open();


                        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                        command.Connection = coneccion;
                        command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM mytable WHERE field not in (1, 2)";

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: is this cut and pasted from your code? if so, did you realise that you have spelt your variable connection differently in multiple places?

Comment: I try to translate the name of the variables so excuse me if i miss some of them, but the main problem is the sql sentence

Comment: in general, you would normally test your where clause in a select before the delete, just to see what the result set (impact) will be. What does the select using that where clause return ?

Comment: i think that the problem is that fox pro couldn't use delete statement with set of values as a condition, because i use this statement in other sql database engines and it works perfectly, so ...

Comment: The FROM clause has the same syntax as in the SQL SELECT command except for the following restrictions: 

The target table or cursor cannot be included in an OUTER join as a secondary table or cursor. 

It should be possible to evaluate all other JOIN operations before performing a JOIN operation on the target table. 

The target cursor cannot be the result from a subquery. 

So perhaps its treating the IN as a sub query...

Comment: if this is your issue, a workaround might be, issue a select with with your where clause to get a resultset of rows you wish to delete, then loop through that result set and delete each individual row using the primary key. Ugly, but should work.

Comment: i solved the problem, i miss close a datareader object and it forbids me to make any operation, thank you all